# Redirect www to non-www using Kohana Framework

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, kohana

I'm using Kohana setup to rewrite index.php for clean URLs. I have the follow htaccess file which works fine for the root domain. However if someone tries going to www.domain.com/learn it will redirect to domain.com/index.php/learn which is incorrect. It should redirect to domain.com/learn

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
#RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

#Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.ericleslie.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ericleslie.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your `bootstrap.php`. `index_file` in `Kohana::init()` isn't set to `FALSE` by default.

Comment: I have it set to FALSE. It works fine when people use the non-www url. It's caused when someone uses the www that it redirects to the non-www and THEN includes the index.php file.